# Разбивка Excel файла: каждый лист сохранить в отдельный файл

Tags: python, excel

Коллеги, доброе время суток. Кто-нибудь знает, как в питоне разбить Excel файл с множеством листов, чтобы каждый лист сохранился в отдельный файл?
И, самое важное, чтобы стили ячеек были сохранены из оригинального файла (выравнивание, объединение и т.д.) Смог осуществить перезапись листов в новые файлы с помощью pandas но, в новых файлах все ячейки "поехали".
Мой код:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob(fr'd:\_temp\*.xls')

count = 0

for file in files:
    sheet_list = pd.ExcelFile(file).sheet_names
    file = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet_list)
    for sheet in file:
        file[sheet].to_excel(f'D:\_temp\{0+count}.xlsx')
        count += 1
```

Comment: https://github.com/Sven-Bo/split-excel-sheet-into-workbook

Comment: гугл не помогает, если им _не пользоваться_. если пользоваться, то нужное находится в первых же результатах.

Comment: Действительно, как я не догадался воспользоваться гуглом.
Но спасибо за пример, хотелось бы конечно разобраться что там написано.
Пойду воспользуюсь гуглом которым я раньше не пользовался

Comment: @user571277 Добрый день! Возможно лучше воспользоваться библиотекой openpyxl load_workbook. Вам нужно будет создать цикл и проходиться по всем листам, в цикле нужно будет создавать новый файл и сохранять его. Попробуйте прогуглите эту библиотеку, возможно, она вам поможет!